# How to ask a Good Question about anything for which there are more than a dozen possible recommendations?

Tags: discussion

Is this site just off limits to anything for which there are many recommendations? Consider the question [Photo editing software for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/340/photo-editing-software-for-windows). There are already three close votes. The answers aren't uniformly *great*, but what possible question could be asked about photo-editing software for Windows that *shouldn't* be closed?

If the consensus is that it and similar questions should be closed, how do expect people to write pithy titles for questions with enough requirements and qualifications to only be satisfied by a 'reasonable' number of possible recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

Just describe what you need and what is important to you. If you do this well then there won't be so many software solutions fulfilling these requirements.

Imagine you buying a car. And you say to the seller:

> I need a car.

What does he recommend you? Whatever he wants - probably the most expensive one or the one he could not sell so far.

If you say

> I need a car with 4 wheels and a radio.

That isn't really better.

But if you go into detail then this will not only help the seller recommend you something useful, it will also be the exact thing you need.

#### But why is that important to future visitors?

We want these recommendations not only be opinions (which can be totally silly) we want the answers to be measurable to say:

> Yes, that recommendation is good because of the facts mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You didn't really address the important aspect of the question, i.e. are questions with more than a handful of Good recommendations Bad questions? Consider the example question; the details actually include does go into detail, but there are still lots of *possible* recommendations. My question was inspired by the three close votes on the example question.

Comment: I don't like to generalize. Not all question with more than 5 answers are bad. How can someone say that?! But the question you refer to is way to broad. It lists only a few basic requirements which many software solutions fulfill. This will become a software list question in time for sure!

Comment: Would you be willing to draw even a fuzzy line as to the number of (possible) recommendations that make a question overly broad? That question seems perfectly fine to me and the answers look perfectly useful. And I'm confused as to what a "software list question" is exactly if it's not any question with more than a single possible recommendation. Besides, the best answers don't merely *mention* a recommendation, they provide details about why it was recommended or even compare and contrast several (good) recommendations.